# Why does my measure with SumX return this result?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables:

```
**Partners**
PartnerID   Name    
1           AAAA    
2           BBBB    
3           CCCC    
4           DDDD

**Sales**
PartnerID   SaleAmount
1           15
2           20
3           30
4           40
1           15
```

I have a visual with PartnerID from my Partners table and this measure:
TotalSalesMeasure: Sumx(Partners, Sum(Sales[SaleAmount]))

```
**Resulting table visual with measure**
PartnerID   TotalSalesMeasure   
1           30  
2           20  
3           30  
4           40
```

What's confusing me is how the results are derived. It's my understanding that:
-The partners table is filtered using the incoming context(PartnerID)
-Filtered partners table is iterated through and Sum(Sales[SaleAmount]) is called for each row
-After Iteration is done, it is summed

First row ex:
-Partners is filtered to 1 row based on the partnerID
-Since it's using row context and not filter context in the partners table, it sums the entire Sales[SaleAmount] column one time
-That should result in 15+20+30+40+15 = 120, but it shows 30

I was basing this on a video here at around the 49 min mark where he does a similar operation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yWLhxYoq88

What's odd is if I do the same thing he does later by wrapping Sum with Calculate, I get the same result(aside from the totals field). In fact, my result seems to be what calculate would return(again, outside of the grand total)

I'm obviously confusing something, but I don't know what it is

Edit:
I think I know what's going on now. The external filter context is applied to the sales table before summing. I didn't realize that it did that as well

SumX(
Partners <---Affected by exterior context
Sum(Sales[SalesAmount]) <---Affected by exterior context + row context
)